# Generator of all possible 8 symbols strings. Brute force 8 symbol password. python

Tags: python, brute-force

I need to write generator which yield all possible 8 symbols strings.
From array of symbols like this:

```
leters = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m']
```

The skeleton looks like this:

```
def generator():
    """
    here algorithm
    """
    yield string
```

suppose to return list like this `['00000001','00000002','00000003', ......'mmmmmmmm']`

Comment: Just a suggestion to use a generator for this, as you will be dealing with over 2 trillion elements.  `itertools.permutations('abcdefgh...', 8)`

Comment: permutations doesn't give you results with repeated elements, eg, any password with two or more 0's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`itertools.combinations()` and `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` return a generator

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> from itertools import combinations
```

I am using `print()` in the examples to illustrate the output. Substitute it with `yield`, to get a generator.

```
>>> for c in combinations(letters, 2): 
        print(c)
... 
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('b', 'c')

>>> for c in combinations(letters, 2): 
        print(''.join(c))
... 
ab
ac
bc
>>> 

>>> for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(letters, 2): 
        print(''.join(c))
... 
aa
ab
ac
bb
bc
cc
```

If you brute force it for all 8 letter passwords containing english letters and digits, you're looking to iterate over ~ 2.8 trillion strings

**EDIT** 
If you somehow know there are no repeated elements, use `permutations`

```
>>> for c in itertools.permutations(letters, 2): 
        print(''.join(c))
... 
ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb
```

this gives you both *ab* and *ba*

For the most general brute force sequence use `itertools.product()` as in Cosmologicon's solution

Comment: This only gives you words in lexicographical order, no? I don't see "ba" on the list.

Answer (score 7):

```
itertools.product(leters, repeat=8)
```

EDIT: to have it give you strings rather than tuples:

```
def generator(leters):
    a = itertools.product(leters,repeat=3)
    while a:
        yield "".join(a.next())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
itertools.combinations_with_replacement(leters, 8)
```

By the way, letters has two T's.

Comment: how much time would this take to complete ?

Comment: @retrocode len (leters) ** 8 * time to process one combination.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering how to do this as well and this is what I came up with I tried it a couple ways but when I wrote it like this it went way quicker than the others...please lmk if I am not seeing

```
import string

from itertools import permutations

[print(*p,sep='')for p in permutations(list(string.ascii_letters+string.punctuation+string.digits),8)]
```

Comment: but i do see if any of them repeat combinations would be needed?

Comment: this is giving output having characters which are not in the string itself . [link](https://ideone.com/afNwvg)